# Can´t compare string from COM-object with string-literal

Tags: c#, com

I have the following code in order to compare a value read from a DB with some expected values:

```
object o = row.get_Value(fieldIndex);
bool equal = o == "mytext";
```

When I debug that `o` has the value `"mytext"`. However the comparison yields `false`. If on the other hand I cast `o` to `string`, the comparison works:

```
bool equal = (string)o == "mytext";
```

While `row` is a COM-object, `o.GetType()` returns `string`.

Unfortunately I cannot provide what `get_Value` does, as I don´t have its sourcecode.

So why does the second comparison work while the first one does not?

Comment: My guess is that the type of `o` is just a reference type of some description that has an implicit string cast.

Comment: *"So why does the second return true?"* - I am confused, you are casting something to string (which produces `"mytext"`) and asking why `"mytext" == "mytext"` is `true`?

Comment: `string` overloads the `==` operator. This overload is called in your second snippet, but not your first.

Comment: @Sinatr to cleariffy: `"mytext"` is interned, so comparing it to `"mytext"` of course returns true. So I´m wondering why it is intered in the second but not in the first case?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yeap, that sounds plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal reproducible example would be

```
object o = "mymy";
string s = "my";
Console.WriteLine(o == s+s);
```

This gives you the compiler warning [CS0252](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0252), which basically says that you get the equality comparison of `object` and not the equality comparison of `string`.

`string` changes the meaning of [`==` to that of `.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.op_equality?view=net-5.0), which tests for character by character equality.